# How to have selective field for deep population query in mongoose

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

My query is as shown below:

```
orderSubInfo.find({
    'order_id': {
        $in: orderArray
    }
}).populate({
    path: 'order_id',
    populate: {
        path: 'foodtruck_id',
        model: 'foodtruck'
    }
}).exec().then((info) => {
    res.json({
        status: '200',
        message: 'Your OTP',
        data: info
    })
}).catch((err) => {
    res.json({
        status: '500',
        message: 'Oops,something went wromg'
    })
});
```

Now what here happens is after `populate {path:foodtruck_id,model:'foodtruck}`. I get unnecessary fields. But I want to have `foodtruck_name,foodtruck_location` only. So how should i modify my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select only the fields you want to include ([mongoose population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)):

```
populate: {
    path: 'foodtruck_id',
    model: 'foodtruck',
    select: 'foodtruck_name foodtruck_location' //to exclude _id add -_id
}
```